# Flutter : How to change Android minSdkVersion in Flutter Project?

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools

I was trying to start a flutter project for an App using Bluetooth to communicate. For that, I was using [flutter blue](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue).

Unfortunately, when trying to run (on an Android device) the first example I created I was met with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
  > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:flutter_blue] /home/maldus/Projects/flutter/polmac/build/flutter_blue/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
            or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
            or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.pauldemarco.flutterblue" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

If I were on Android Studio, I'd know how to bump up the Android minSdkVersion, but on a Flutter project (using VSCode) I was a little lost.

Is it possible to increase the minSdkVersion with Flutter, and how?

Comment: Background info on minSdkVersion that may be helpful:  https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/sdk-versions#minsdkversion

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70485898/where-is-the-value-of-flutter-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project-initialized

Answer (score 520, accepted):

It is indeed possible to increase minSdkVersion, but it took me way too much time to find it out because google searches mostly yields as result discussions about the absolute minimum Sdk version flutter should be able to support, not how to increase it in your own project.

Like in an Android Studio project, you have to edit the `build.gradle` file. In a flutter project, it is found at the path `./android/app/build.gradle`.

The parameter that needs to be changed is, of course, `minSdkVersion 16`, bumping it up to what you need (in this case 19).

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.projectname"
    minSdkVersion 19 //*** This is the part that needs to be changed, previously was 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Seems obvious now, but took me long enough to figure it out on my own.

Comment: The file-path was very helpful! I was looking at the build.gradle file under `android/` and couldn't figure out for the life of me how to get this minSdkVersion to be updated.

Comment: What if I do not want to change the minSdkVersion as I want to target the lower SDK versions? @Maldus

Comment: Then don't change it? I'm not sure I understand the question, I hit this issue because flutterblue did not work without changing the minSDKVersion. If you want to use flutterblue with a lower SDK version I'm afraid that's a problem of the flutter library.

Comment: @pblead26 Facing the same issue. Seems no other way apart from increasing minSdkVersion.

Comment: Using this approach is not a good idea! The answers from Francis Nduba & (Mr Random & Jahidul Islam) provide two good approaches. Approach from (Mr Random & Jahidul Islam) should be used when you want to override the minSdkVersion for a particular project only and want to keep the default minSdkVersion unchanged. The approach from Francis Nduba should be used when you want to use a particular minSdkVersion for all of your flutter projects. Generally, you should not change the default flutter minSdkVersion for all projects unless required by any of your packages/features.

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.flutterbeads.com/change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter/) article to update mindSdkVersion in flutter

Answer (score 288):

**Flutter 2.8 or Later**

`build.gradle` update

Before Updating to Flutter 2.8

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

After updating to Flutter 2.8:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

You should change from `local.properties` following instruction:

1. First go to the android->local.properties

[image]

2. And changes from here

[image]

3. Change like this from build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
    targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Comment: do you know why it doesn't appear while i created new project?

Comment: Actually, it is generated by default, but if you don't get in the android folder then create it manually.

Comment: It's not working for me

Comment: after setting sdk please restart your ide or manually set the value in build.gradle

Comment: you cant directly read  `flutter.minSdkVersion ` use `localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion')` check out my  answer
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project/70452027#70452027

Comment: I get &gt; Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object Error when building for release

Comment: `local.properties` file is normally not under [source control](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/0ce527eb91a37ef31b60ed6d4a9613310f2107d4/.gitignore#L68). So I don't think is a good place where to have important non-local config like this.

Comment: again got an issue :
   > One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:
     Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0-alpha05' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

Comment: @DavidMiguel See `@GelidGeorge` answer below for what i consider a much better solution with the recent default configuration. It considers the local.properties values but defaults to hardcoded props if unset.

Comment: @DavidMiguel then, where and how would you do it?

Answer (score 180):

If you didn't know, Google Playstore only allows minSdkVersion to be 20 or above. But flutter has still set default minSdkVersion to 16. Can you see that you'll be always obliged to manually change for each new project?

All your suggestions above are good, but they are not the best, because you will be forced to temper with the ***build.gradle*** for each new project you create.

The best way is to modify the value of the *global minSdkVersion variable* from its source, so all projects, new or old, will adopt it. Remember ***flutter.minSdkVersion*** means that the variable is in ***flutter*** directory (with the sdk).

The file in question is ***flutter.gradle***.

the address is ***flutter-directory/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle***

```
class FlutterExtension {
    /** Sets the compileSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int compileSdkVersion = 31

    /** Sets the minSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int minSdkVersion = 16

    /** Sets the targetSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int targetSdkVersion = 31
```

change the value of the minSdkVersion from 16 to 20 or above, and do not disturb the code in ***build.gradle***.

If you want, you can watch a video I made on Youtube, explaining it under: [flutter configure minSdkVersion from 16 to 20 or above](https://youtu.be/501rLKAW3k4)

=======================

UPDATED RESPONSE DUE TO CHANGES WITH FLUTTER 3.13 AND ABOVE

With this version forward, the content of this file ***flutter-directory/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle*** has been moved to this new location ***flutter-directory/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy***. And the default `minSdkVersion = 19`. But for the sake of being safe with the latest packages and android devices, it is better to set it at `minSdkVersion = 20`.

Comment: Thanks @Francis Nduba Numbi, this is by far the best answer. That way I don't have to make changes on every individual project. My approach is to always target higher versions by default and only do backward compatibility for certain projects.

Comment: Thank you. You can vote as the best answer and close it. it will very much help.

Comment: I would argue that you should change the build.gradle file. Changing the global variable only affects your own system, so if someone else on your team (or a CI/CD pipeline) clones the project, they will have trouble building it.

Comment: Nice point. Then, you should leave a note in ReadMe to inform of the minimum minSdkVersion

Comment: Good information about **flutter.gradle** file, thanks @FrancisNdubaNumbi

Comment: I'm sorry, this is an extremely bad answer. You shouldn't be changing the source of the tool if you want to change the project. This means a project in source control doesn't have its own build info defined (it won't compile the same on different computers), that EVERY project on one's computer will be using that version, and that upgrading Flutter will break it. The tool should be independent of the project. To be clear: this should NOT BE DONE under ANY CIRCUMSTANCE no matter how "easy" it looks. Anyone wanting to pin their build to a specific version should edit `build.gradle` directly.

Comment: Google Playstore requests that minSdkVersion be 20 or above, only that flutter has not updated it to meet the requirements. So what the need to keep it at 16 knowing that you will be obliged to manually change it for every project ?

Comment: <flutterSDKDirectory>/packages/............

Comment: I do not recommend using this answer. This should be set at the project level

Comment: If you didn't know, Google Playstore only allows minSdkVersion to be 20 or above. But flutter has still set default minSdkVersion to 16. Can you see that you'll be always obliged to manually change for each new project?

Comment: Good point and this should be voted as the best answer - change once and use in all flutter projects

Comment: NEVER adopt a solution which won't be reflected in your source code control. Any other dev should be able to install the tools, take your code, and compile as is... Flutter might be wrong to still specify rev 16, but again this should be worked around in your project files. Nice info on the default settings location though!

Comment: Can you please back up your claim that 'Google Playstore only allows minSdkVersion to be 20 or above'. I can't find this mentioned anywhere in Google's documentation. I can only see targetSdkVersion mentioned in Google's documentation, but targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion are different things.

Comment: If you have ever deployed an app on Playstore, you will have noticed that requirement of minimum SDK version. I have stated it by experience, not by reading documentations.

Comment: It's completely incorrect that Google Play requires minSdkVersion to be high. Just sampling the apps on my phone, several perfectly good apps from the Play Store have minSdkVersion of 19 or less, some as low as 14. And there's zero reason why Google would make such a requirement. // What you are thinking of is the requirements on the *target* SDK version, which is a very different thing. Flutter defaults to a targetSdkVersion of 33, the latest version, as it should.

Comment: My friend. I have put many apps on playstore recently. if the minSdkVerison is less that 20, it will not pass. When you say it is incorrect, is it out of experience or out of assumptions ? older apps which are updated may still have minSdkVersion lower than 20.  But newly put apps will not.

Comment: In fact for a better performance of your app, better set the minSdkVersion to 21.

Comment: In flutter version 3.13.0^, you should edit the file: flutter-directory\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy

Comment: i have gitlab ci build and sdk is in external docker image. is it possible to set minSdkVersion in gitlab-ci?

Answer (score 66):

**For flutter v2.8**

Inside local.properties add

```
sdk.dir='<path>'
flutter.sdk='<path>'
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1

flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=30
flutter.compileSdkVersion=30
```

app-level build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
    targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Now you can use `localProperties.getProperty()` to read the value from the properties file.

Answer (score 47):

You can change the `minSdkVersion` in the file `Project_Name/android/app/build.gradle` , `defaultconfig` :

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.projectname"
    minSdkVersion 16 // <--- There
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 41):

**Here the detailed solution for changing MinSdk /Minsdk version error, follow the steps.**

**Add following lines on android\local.properties**

```
sdk.dir=
flutter.sdk=C:\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1

flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=31
flutter.compileSdkVersion=31
```

[image: android\local.properties]

**Delete existing lines and paste it on app level build.gradle: android\app\build.gradle**

```
       defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app-id"

        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 37):

With the new Flutter projects (2.8.0), with the 'Flutter style', you able to change minimum sdk version in local.properties (instead of editing app/build.gradle file).

```
# android/local.properties

flutter.minSdkVersion=19
```

Look in android/app/build.gradle file, you'll see the variable constraint like this:

```
# android/app/build.gradle

android {

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
  }
}
```

Comment: do we need to create it manually?

Comment: Yes, local.properties ignored by .gitignore by default, you should create one if not exists.

Answer (score 26):

**Add the following lines to android/local.properties file:**

```
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.versionName=0.0.1
flutter.flutterMinSdkVersion=24
flutter.flutterTargetSdkVersion=31
```

**Add the following lines at the top-level in the file may be after "def versionName =" in the file android/app/build.gradle:**

```
def flutterMinSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.flutterMinSdkVersion')
if (flutterMinSdkVersion == null) {
    flutterMinSdkVersion = '16'
}

def flutterTargetSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.flutterTargetSdkVersion')
if (flutterTargetSdkVersion == null) {
    flutterTargetSdkVersion = '31'
}
```

**finally edit the section of the build.gradle that match as follows:**

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "do.main.subdomain" // Use your App ID
        minSdkVersion flutterMinSdkVersion.toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion flutterTargetSdkVersion.toInteger()
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

**Once all this is done you are good to go. Next time you want to update something you only have to change one file.**

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer. Applying defaults for when local.properites are null. `local.properites` is not the correct place to put build versions and is just asking for trouble unless your testing for a specific release.

Comment: Agree - best answer.

Answer (score 15):

All answers are best. But the following way is best in changing SdkVersion after Flutter 2.8 :

Go to your root directory where flutter is installed. It should be like

```
C:\src\flutter\flutter
```

Then go to

```
packages>Flutter tools>gradle>
```

In Gradle, you will see many files, locate flutter.gradle . Right-click on it and edit it with text editor/notepad.

here you will find all SDK versions. Change them, save, and then you are ready to go

the complete path should be like this: (in my case)

```
C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle
```

[image: In the image you can see SDKs]

Comment: I was looking for this one, thanks!

Comment: Hello @Aizan Sagheer

Answer (score 13):

For flutter version **3.x.x** on MacBook M series chips,

File for minSdkVersion to change is

```
/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy.flutter.groovy
```

- Change minSdkVersion to at least 21.
- Currently, compileSdkVersion should be at least 35

```java
/** Sets the compileSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int compileSdkVersion = 35

/** Sets the minSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int minSdkVersion = 21

/** Sets the targetSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int targetSdkVersion = 35
```

Answer (score 11):

This is how I approached when I got this issue recently:

Inside `<your-project>/android/app/build.gradle`

Find android -> defaultConfig -> minSdkVersion and replace it with

`minSdkVersion Math.max(flutter.minSdkVersion, 21)`

21 here can be replaced by whatever minimum version you would want.

In case flutter start supporting 23 or some other higher version as the minimum version and you decide to upgrade flutter for your project, it would still work.

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps to change the `minSdkVersion` problem.

First=> `YouProject_name/android/app/build.gradle`

Second=> defaultconfig { //you can find it inside `build.gradle` }

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.umair.product_details_using_crud"
        minSdkVersion 16 // here you can change minSdkVersison
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    **android/local.properties**
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=30
flutter.compileSdkVersion=31

  **android/app/build.gradle**
minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()

targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the best way to fix this so it performs globally across all of your future apps as well is by changing the setting in the flutter.gradle file located in your default build section. If you're using VSCode

1. go to this location (or the location you've installed flutter)
   C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\
2. drag the flutter.gradle file into VSCode
3. update the min, compile, and/or target versions
4. save

Answer (score 3):

In build.gradle you'll find the below

```
android {
   ...
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ...
```

You could replace flutter.compileSdkVersion with a hard coded number, or read it from a property file, as many others have suggested.

However, you could change the variable flutter.compileSdkVersion itself. This is located in the file flutter.groovy, located in your flutter SDK directory, subdirectory packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy. For example: C:\dev\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy

In this file, you'll find:

```
class FlutterExtension {
    /** Sets the compileSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int compileSdkVersion = 33

    /** Sets the minSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int minSdkVersion = 21

    /** Sets the targetSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int targetSdkVersion = 33
```

Change these variables in the value you need.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem setting up Auth0, flutter_appauth and flutter_secure_storage within my flutter app. After changing the minSdkVersion version, I got this error

```
C:\Users\myusername\AndroidStudioProjects\wole\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Attribute data@scheme at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <appAuthRedirectScheme> is provided.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute data@scheme at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for  is provided.

The solution is adding manifestPlaceholders thus

[image: view image]

Answer (score 1):

Setting minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and compileSdkVersion are a little bit different starting from Flutter 2.8. Now the gradle file in `your_flutter_app/android/app/build.gradle` path looks like this:

[image]

Just replace the current values with the version numbers you want, like this:

[image]

Now run your flutter project, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

change local.properties file mentioned below.. because currently playstore update minimum target api version atleast 30

```
sdk.dir=/Users/sweetnandha/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/sweetnandha/FlutterDev/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.compileSdkVersion=32
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=32
```

[image]

or

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Flutter version 3.16 (and may be greater)***

If you can't find minSdk, compileSdk or targerSDK and all you see is

```
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
```

Then you can go to where your `flutter` main folder is and from there

the address is ***flutter-directory/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy***

Answer (score 0):

It's found inside the defaultconfig on [project_name]/android/app/build.gradle. defaultconfig

Answer (score 0):

you can find out that folder with `which flutter` ( on mac or linux ) or in windows you can look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/304447/8122500 .
then you can follow guide from @francis-nduba-numbi .

there is 2 type to change from

1. from `flutter.gradle` ( recommendation change here for not spesifc/for future )
2. or direct from `build.gradle` ( not recommended )

Answer (score 0):

Try this at `android/app/build.gradel` `minSdkVersion 30` that should fix it but make sure you are at `kotlin_version = '1.6.10'` with your kotlin version.

Answer (score -1):

[[image]`app/build.gradle` add this version code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysjcD.png)

Answer (score -1):

In the current version of flutter (2.10.4) you should change it by going into
Flutter sdk folder/packages/open flutter_tools open /gradle then open flutter.gradle and find static int minSdkVersion and change as per requirement

e.g:
**C:\Workspace\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle**

[image: This is what you'll see in the flutter.gradle file]

Answer (score -1):

defaultConfig {
// TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
applicationId "com.example.map"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
}

Answer (score -2):

if you would like to set **as global.**

here is, just simple run `flutter doctor -v` and you will get your sdk location

> , i think override sdk version in every projects is not good in the future.

```
➜  ~ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-arm, locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at /Users/yogiarifwidodo/dev/flutter
```

**first**

```
➜  ~ cd /Users/yogiarifwidodo/dev/flutter/
```

**then**

```
➜  flutter git:(stable) ✗ cd packages/flutter_tools/gradle
```

**last**

```
nano flutter.gradle
```

**editing**

```
ctrl + w , then type `compileSdk`
modif your sdk number
then `ctrl + x`
then `y`
then enter to save
```

Answer (score -3):

Upgrade your compiled sdk version to 29 - higher

hope this will help you.

Answer (score -4):

first run
**flutter clean**

then change the minSdkVersion in the file *Project_Name/android/app/build.gradle , defaultconfig :*