# About Gradle and Android platform in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, platform

Excuse me,
I am new to Flutter, so when I install Flutter, I see that the Gradle version from distribution url is still 5.6.2 while the latest is 6.4.1.
The Kotlin is also not the latest, and the android platform has no sdk.
So do I have to update all of them to the latest or just leave them there ? And should I put the platform to 29 or 28 ? Or just leave it there ?
Thank you for your time !!!

Answer (score 0):

Setting up sdk for project:

Go to

1. Android studio `File` menu
2. `Project structure`
3. select Under `Project setting` -> `Project`
4. Select & set the latest sdk for `Project SDK`

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! so Project SDK should be set to the latest ! But how about the gradle version? and kotlin version ?

Comment: If you want to update them  then you can go to android project and update the versions in root project build.gradle file. otherwise if its not causing any issue for you then its fine to leave it as its.

Comment: Ok thank you, I try updating it and it still work fine... dunno if it will cause any problem later ... Anyway, thank you a lot for your answer !!!

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project) may help you to get more about SDK subject (`minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, `compileSdkVersion` and `build.gradle`).

Due I used deliverr my apps to support SDK compatibility with very old devices from 16 (Android 4.1) to the latest level, after I upgraded an Android phone to version 11 (SDK level = 30), I had to update my `build.gradle` from (`targetSdkVersion 28` and `compileSdkVersion 28`) to (`targetSdkVersion 30` and `compileSdkVersion 30`) to get all working back again.

To know more about SDK Platform levels and Android versions, please visit [this website](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms).