# Build Failed in Flutter, Couldn't understand the error

Tags: flutter

This is the error that I'm getting.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:razorpay_flutter] D:\All Data\My Projects\Mine Created Flutter Projects\gym_work\build\razorpay_flutter\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.razorpay.razorpay_flutter" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Thanks to Maldus!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project

Comment: go to android folder > app > src folder. open `build.gradle` file. find a line `minSdkVersion 16`. change to `minSdkVersion 19`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
android{
  defaultConfig{
    minSdkVersion 19
  }
}
```

to `android/app/build.gradle` in you project directory