# Does Flutter work on any Android platform version?

Tags: android, flutter, version

I'm newbie on Android programming, but I've heard about one should be careful with the Android version when programming. So far, while I'm learning Flutter, I've not read on any book/article such a warning, it seems that new Flutter/widgets versions are independent on any Android platform version. That is, Can a Flutter app running on Android API 29 run on old Android API 10? If it is not, how can I know on what Android platform versions my current Flutter app can run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Flutter FAQ](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on):

> What devices and OS versions does Flutter run on?
> Mobile operating systems: Android Jelly Bean, v16, 4.1.x or newer, and iOS 8 or newer.
>
> Mobile hardware: iOS devices (iPhone 4S or newer) and ARM Android devices.
>
> Flutter supports building ahead-of-time (AOT) compiled libraries for x86_64, armeabi-v7a, and arm64-v8a.
>
> Apps built for ARMv7 or ARM64 run fine (using ARM emulation) on many x86 Android devices.
>
> We support developing Flutter apps with Android and iOS devices, as well as with Android emulators and the iOS simulator.
>
> We test on a variety of low-end to high-end phones and tablets, but we don’t yet have an official device compatibility guarantee.

So it appears SDK version 16 is the minimum, and you can change the versions you are targeting [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060517/9872288).

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about not working on android because by default the minimum sdk version is 21 but can be set to anything app-on creating the project.

Comment: 95% of phones has a sdk version higher then 21