# flutter_smart_cropper uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library

Tags: flutter

I am trying to install [flutter_smart_cropper package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_smart_cropper) on flutter (adding `flutter_smart_cropper: ^0.1.2` in `pubspec.yaml`, run `flutter pub get`, run `flutter run`), and met the following error:

```
/Users/[USERNAME]/Flutter-QuickStart/my_flutter_smart_cropper/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:flutter_smart_cropper] /Users/[USERNAME]/Flutter-QuickStart/my_flutter_smart_cropper/build/flutter_smart_cropper/intermediates/library_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.xbo1.flutter_smart_cropper" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.                  
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:flutter_smart_cropper] /Users/[USERNAME]/Flutter-QuickStart/my_flutter_smart_cropper/build/flutter_smart_cropper/intermediates/library_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.xbo1.flutter_smart_cropper" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Can someone explain what does it mean to increase this project's minSDK version to at least 19, and how do I do so?

Comment: Increase minSdkVersion 16 to 19 under ./android/app/build.gradle file

Answer (score 4):

The package requires higher minSDK version. You need to upgrade it in `./android/app/build.gradle`

You can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060517/4684512)

Comment: thanks! took me long enough to locate the right build.gradle file

Answer (score -1):

//go to android/app/build.gradle
defaultConfig {
// TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
applicationId "com.example.edit_profile"
// You can update the following values to match your application needs.
// For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
//Now you just have to remove this flutter.minSdkVersion
// and write 19
//minSdkVersion 19
// so sync the code it will run
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).