# Upgrading flutter android build tools

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, build-tools, flutter-android

Flutter is building apk on android API level 29 by default I want to upgrade it to 30 how can I? I am new to flutter I don't know, I tried to google it but it wasn't helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a Flutter project in  Android Studio  and you have to edit the build.gradle file. In a flutter project, it is found at the path `./android/app/build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.projectname"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28 // Set this to 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060517/9722336) answer and modified accordingly