# How to update minSdkVersion in flutter updated 2.8?

Tags: flutter, dart

Before updating to Flutter 2.8

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kim.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

After updating to Flutter 2.8:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

How can I update minSdkVersion higher? I cannot find the target "flutter.minSdkVersion" variable anywhere.

Comment: follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project/70316521#70316521

Answer (score 17):

### Go to android/local.properties

Add the following ie define the versions

- flutter.minSdkVersion=21
- flutter.targetSdkVersion=30
- flutter.compileSdkVersion=30

### Once done goto android/app/build.gradle and add the following

minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()

targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()

### Then goto android/build.gradle

Update the Kotlin version

ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 12):

just replace flutter.minSdkVersion with your value ,

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just replace `flutter.minSdkVersion` to your target version.

`flutter.minSdkVersion` is found in
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/stable/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle

Answer (score 0):

**Go to android/local.properties**
there you can change configuration