# How do I update minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in the new version of flutter 2.8.0

Tags: flutter, dart, targetsdkversion

On file **build.gradle** I found code like this

`minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion`

`targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion`

How can I change the values from where they are initialized ? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzEl8.jpg)

Comment: I open android Studio File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Default Config and select Target SDK Version And Min SDK Version

Comment: Check out my  answer
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project/70452027#70452027

Answer (score 10):

You can simply change these in `android/local.properties` file.

define or change them inside `android/local.properties`:

```dart
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

// add these lines
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=29
```

Comment: Thank you so much but if you don't mind can you check this file:
C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle
inside file flutter.gradle there's :
Class  FlutterExtension {
  static int compileSdkVersion = 31

    /** Sets the minSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int minSdkVersion = 16

    /** Sets the targetSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int targetSdkVersion = 31
}

Comment: @rachidev So what is wrong with this file?

Comment: Nothing wrong, but I guess this is the source where flutter get the values of flutter.minSdkVersion and
flutter.targetSdkVersion

Answer (score 9):

flutter 2.9.2
in [prj]/android/app/src/build.gradle
change :

```
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
```

to (for example) :

```
minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion')
```

and in [prj]/android/local.properties add/change:

```
flutter.minSdkVersion=XX
```

Comment: Thanks this did work. The top comment is not complete. This one is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion

targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion

With this

minSdkVersion 21

targetSdkVersion 31

versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()

versionName flutterVersionName