# How to change minSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion in flutter 2.8?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, version

I just upgrade my flutter sdk to latest version which is 2.8 and created new project and I don't see old way of changing  minimum and tarketVersion sdk instead I can see

```
 minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
 targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

Question is What is the best way or recommended approach here,where can I find folder/file (flutter.) in project.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project/70316521#70316521