# Where is the value of "flutter.minSdkVersion" in Flutter project initialized?

Tags: android, flutter, android-min-sdk

I have created a new Flutter project, and this is how the minSdkVersion looks like in the `app/build.gradle` file:

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.projectname"
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Where is the value of `flutter.minSdkVersion` set?

Note that previously, that config value looked like the following:

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.projectname"
    minSdkVersion 19 //*** This is the part that needs to be changed, previously was 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Also, this is the content of the `android/local.properties` file:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/usernaem/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/username/flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

As you can see, the value of `flutter.minSdkVersion` is not set there, but the project can be compiled and built successfully.

Where are the `flutter.minSdkVersion` and `flutter.targetSdkVersion` variables initialized?

P.S. related issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95533

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Android minSdkVersion in flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project/70316521#70316521)

Comment: Obviously not! Previously the value was something like `minSdkVersion 19` and it was easy to change it. But now it's set via a variable `minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion` and I don't know where it's set.

Comment: go to android folder and then android->local.properties and here you change your require SDK version

Comment: I cannot see them there. Updated the question with the content of the `local.properties` file.

Answer (score 18):

Go to this file in your flutter extracted folder:

flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle

There you can find all static variables.

Comment: I was wondering where does this `flutter.minSdkVersion` come from as well.

Comment: It is not the best way to do this. minSdkVersion can be vary per project. Check local.properties instead.

Answer (score 4):

To complement `Jay Goti`'s answer. On a newer Flutter project (3.13.9), the file at `flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle` will only have the following two lines:

```
def pathToThisDirectory = buildscript.sourceFile.parentFile
apply from: "$pathToThisDirectory/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy"
```

So you have to refer to the mentioned file instead, at:
`flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy`

There you'll find all the info:

```
...

/** Sets the compileSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
static int compileSdkVersion = 33

/** Sets the minSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
static int minSdkVersion = 19

/** Sets the targetSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
static int targetSdkVersion = 33

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `flutter.minSdkVersion` with your required value such as `19` like old style

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.projectname"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Comment: only hardcore, only hardcode! XD

Answer (score 0):

Put in your `android/local.propertie` file the variable:

Example:

```
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
```

And change in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
localProperties.getProperties('flutter.minSdkVersion') // flutter.minSdkVersion
```

Comment: It should be localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()

Comment: For me works without .toInteger()

Comment: local.propertie is usually ignored in the .gitignore. So, the setup will be necessary on each machine. Is there any other way that only affects the given project and is included in git? Why changing the build.gradle is not an option? Can we create a separate file like "project.properties" instead (idk how since the reading is done using an internal method)?

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the path /android/app/build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.sample.com"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```