# Flutter build failed after `flutter upgrade` to 2.10

Tags: flutter

What is causing the following build exception in an existing Flutter project after upgrading flutter to 2.10?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Blah\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\602ce26881e3b92788ae83c190d3c36f\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Blah\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9520e6f13992d2f4d96b17b856330597\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Flutter 2.10 support for Foldable devices via AndroidX

Flutter 2.10 [added support for foldable Android devices](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/kotlin-version).

This relies on Android SDK API version 31's [AndroidX library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) dependency of: `androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0`

##### The build failed because:

1. this new AndroidX dependency requires Android compileSdkVersion of 31 or higher.
2. It also requires `kotlin_version` of `1.5.31` or higher.

So existing Flutter/Android projects may need some gradle file changes:

##### `android/build.gradle`:

- bump `ext.kotlin_version` to at least `1.5.31` (`1.6.10` is available as of Feb 2022)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
```

##### `android/app/build.gradle`

- bump `compileSdkVersion` to `31` or higher

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
```

---

If you don't have Android 12 SDK (API level 31) installed...

### Install & Use SDK API 31 (Android 12) in Android Studio

#### In Android Studio

- go to Tools > SDK Manager > tick/check Android 12 (S) API Level 31 > click OK button > wait for download/install

[image: Android Studio install SDK 31]

#### Platform & Project Settings

Next we need to add Android SDK API 31 to our Project Structure under both Platform Settings *and* Project Settings

- Android Studio > File > Project Structure
- Under **Platform Settings** click **SDKs**
- In the middle column click **+** icon button, select "Add Android SDK.."
- You will be prompted to select an Android SDK directory

  - Select your Android Sdk ***root directory*** like `C:\Android\Sdk`
  - **do not** select the specific API version like `C:\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31`. This will be rejected.

[image: Add SDK to Platform Settings]

- A "Create New Android SDK" window will pop up.
- By default Java SDK 11 & Build target: Android API 31 will be preselected.  If not, select them.
- Click OK.

[image: Select Build Target]

- Android API 31 Platform is now available for your Project.
- Now under ***Project*** **Settings**, click on **Project**

[image: Platforms available]

- On the right under **Project SDK:**
- Click the dropdown list
- Select **Android API 31 Platform**
- Click OK

[image: Select API 31 Platform]

- We're done.

Android 12 SDK API 31 is now installed and ready to compile this project.

Comment: Sorry, this did not work for me. I wonder why the upgrade to flutter 2.10 is not working no matter what i tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should Set both compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31 in your build.gradle(app) file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 // <-- This
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        targetSdkVersion 31 // <-- and this too
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no hard requirement that `targetSdkVersion` be equal to `compileSdkVersion` and it will not solve the issue in the original question.   Target SDK specifies general behavior for apps dictated by that API level.  Compile SDK specifies which platform interfaces are available for an application to call.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269079/2301224) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> 

I hade the same issue, all those listed above did not for me, what worked for me is that i downgrade the geolocator from 9.0.1 to 7.7.0

> 