# Are "flutter.targetSdkVersion", "flutter.compileSdkVersion" and "flutter.minSdkVersion" configurable?

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

Recently I've noted Flutter has done some changes to `android\app\build.gradle`, it is not using numeric values for `compileSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` anymore, instead it is using **flutter.compileSdkVersion**, **flutter.minSdkVersion** and **flutter.targetSdkVersion** respectively.

So my question is: Where/How are those values configured? because I don't find info on Web.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project/70316521#70316521

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set these values on `android/local.properties` like so,

```
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.minSdkVersion = 21
flutter.targetSdkVersion = 29
flutter.compileSdkVersion = 30
flutter.ndkVersion=21.0.6011959
```

Update version numbers as required.

Comment: This overrides the values that are dynamically set by Flutter.

Comment: In long run you will eventually use this. As we do not update flutter all the time due to breaking changes every now and then. So the default values set in flutter will get outdated as Android demands new version requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In a Flutter project, when you see a line like targetSdkVersion `flutter.targetSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` file (typically located in android/app/build.gradle), it's a reference to a variable that Flutter dynamically sets to specify the Android target SDK version for your project.

To determine the value of the `flutter.targetSdkVersion`, you could do the following:

You can modify your Android Gradle script to include a custom task that prints out the targetSdkVersion. Here's a small snippet you can add to your android/app/build.gradle file:

```
task printTargetSdkVersion {
    doLast {
        println("Target SDK Version: ${android.defaultConfig.targetSdkVersion}")
    }
}
```

After adding this task, you can execute it by running `./gradlew printTargetSdkVersion` from your Android project directory (usually your_flutter_project/android/). This command should print the targetSdkVersion to the console like this:

> Task :app:printTargetSdkVersion Target SDK Version:
> DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=33, mCodename='null'}
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 961ms