# Android minSdkVersion with Flutter(v2.8.1)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-manifest

I have installed the firebase package. as we know `minSdkVersion 19` is recommended. So, I wanted to do this process. however, I saw that this line is included in the `android/app/build.gradle` file

```
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
```

The previous view would be as follows

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

Is it possible to change the version with a file? that is, whether the value for minSdkVersion is split into another file?

Thanks!

Comment: check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project/

Comment: @JahidulIslam Mashallah. Thanks dear :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add these lines in your **android/local.properties**

```
sdk.dir=/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/{username}/Developer/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1

flutter.minSdkVersion=21         // new
flutter.targetSdkVersion=30      // new
flutter.compileSdkVersion=30     // new
```

then in your **android/app/build.gradle** replace these three lines

```
    minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
    targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
```

Comment: worked fine.. but why cant we directly replace it with number (eg: minSdkVersion 16)

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
```

to **android/local.properties** solved the issue for me.