# Set Android minSdkVersion for Flutter & Pub

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub

**Is it possible to configure a Flutter app with a minimum Android SDK Version such that pub wont try and install dependency that require a higher android sdk version?**

I've cloned a few repositories such as https://github.com/stonega/tsacdop and https://github.com/Teifun2/nextcloud-cookbook-flutter.

These have dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` like

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  #for app key
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
```

When I execute `flutter run` I end up with error messages like:

```
Warning: The plugin path_provider_android requires Android SDK version 31.
Warning: The plugin url_launcher_android requires Android SDK version 31.
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to /projects/sandbox/tsacdop/android/app/build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 31
  ...
}
```

In my case I want to **use the app on Android 11 (SDK Version 30)**, so updating the minimum version isn't the solution I'm looking for.   Though I did follow [How to change Android minSdkVersion in flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project), but configuring `android/app/src/build.gradle` as suggested did **not work:**

```
defaultConfig {
   // setting these did NOT fix the compile errors
   minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
   targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
}
```

I've tried setting dependency to an explicit version in the `pubspec.yaml` file, which fixes some of the dependencies as a one-off, but it would be nice to find a universal solution.

Comment: It isn't asking you to update your `minSdkVersion` or your `targetSdkVersion`, it is asking you to change your `compileSdkVersion` which is something [entirely different](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd).

Comment: Setting `compileSdkVersion` was what I was missing, thank you kindly for the background!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign your required SDK versions Like below. this will solve your compile error.

```
defaultConfig {
  minSdkVersion 31
  targetSdkVersion 31
}
```

or you can change flutter.minSdkVersion and flutter.targetSdkVersion directly from flutter>packages>Flutter_tools>gradle>flutter.gradle
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71440248/10936691