# Error with the version of sdk how can i fix

Tags: flutter

D:\messages_app\chat_app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] D:\messages_app\chat_app\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] D:\messages_app\chat_app\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16      Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)  Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> How to fix this problem?

My build grandle:
defaultConfig {

```
    applicationId "com.coders.chatapp"
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion 
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore needs higher verion of the *minSdkVersion* to work. As you see, you need at least verion 19.

Check this answer, it should fix your problem.

[Try this stackowerflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project)

Answer (score 0):

```
applicationId "com.coders.chatapp"
minSdkVersion 20 //change which sdk version you want 
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
multiDexEnabled true
```