# Flutter Android set compileSdkVersion in local.properties file

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

If I set `compileSdkVersion 33` in build.gradle, it's ok.
But it's kind of hard code, so I try to set it in `local.properties` file.

As I already set `flutter.minSdkVersion=23` in that file, I think `flutter.compileSdkVersion=33` works the same, but it's not.

Details:

local.properties file:

```
flutter.compileSdkVersion=33
```

build.gradle file:

```
def flutterCompileSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion')
if (flutterCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    flutterCompileSdkVersion = flutter.compileSdkVersion
}

...

compileSdkVersion flutterCompileSdkVersion // error here
compileSdkVersion 33 // this works
```

Error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/vietstone-ng/Library/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 461

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > String index out of range: -6

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 785ms
```

Is there anyway to set compileSdkVersion inside local.properties file?

Answer (score 12):

I was able to set it using local.properties this way:

```
// in YourProject/android/app/build.gradle
...
android {  
    compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()
    ...
}
```

The following did not work

```
  android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ...
```

Originally answered by [Maldus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862613/maldus) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project)