# How to properly update minSdkVersion on Flutter 3.0.5?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle, android-sdk-tools

I am getting this error after updating minSdkVersion according to this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project/70316521#70316521).

Here is the error.

(For some reason I can't post the raw error output.)
[image: Error]

Here is my build.gradle:

```
    defaultConfig {
    
       applicationId "com.example.test_app"
    

       // modified this as per the solution
       minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty(‘flutter.minSdkVersion’).toInteger()
       targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
       versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
       versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Here is my local.propertis

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\userone\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1

// added this as per the solution
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
```

Comment: Can you please tell what is the error, because in your logs above it just shows that an error has occured while building but it doesn't tell the error.

Comment: @JustaPerson Thanks. I didn't notice that. Please check now.

Comment: In the image you have posted in that line, localProperties.getProperty('') It looks like you have used backticks ` instead of single quote ' and I think that's the reason why you can't post the logs on stack overflow. Or try to copy and paste the complete code from that answer to avoid any mistakes.

Comment: @JustaPerson new error occurs: Parameter format not correct -

Comment: On which line does the error occur? Can you post the error message or post the screenshot if you can't get the error message posted here?