# I can't use command "webview_flutter", can't change minSdkVersion version

Tags: flutter, webview, webview-flutter

I want to use "webview" command in flutter. It should be "minSdkVersion 19" but there is no line of code to change in my "build_gradle" file.

```
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.webviewkullanimi.webview_kullanimi"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Android minSdkVersion in flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project)

Answer (score 0):

You should change from local.properties following instruction:

1- Go to the android->local.properties

2- Change the value of the property that you want to change

Comment: Cannot find "minSdkVersion"

Answer (score 0):

i can clearly seen there on 3rd line it's showing minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion change it to

```
minSdkversion 19
```