# How to change sdk version: I have changed manually in pubspec.yaml but it does not work

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, sdk

I have changed manually in pubspec.yaml file but it does not work.

Error:

> pub get failed (1; Because my_app depends on geolocator >=9.0.1 which requires SDK version >=2.15.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Android minSdkVersion in flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project)

Comment: add pubspec.yaml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in `pubspec.yaml` change with

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: i have done this but it does not work

Comment: Could you provide the output of `flutter doctor`?

Answer (score 0):

- You can get all the flutter sdk versions here.
  https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases

- then try running this in terminal brother,

if you want to downgrade to an specific flutter version

- flutter downgrade  (example: flutter downgrade v1.2.1)

if you want to upgrade to a specific flutter version

- flutter upgrade  (example: flutter upgrade v1.2.1)

then run flutter --version to check the current version.

Have fun and Keep Coding!

Comment: i found the answer in terminal run flutter upgrade or try flutter upgrade --force