# Flutter - Requires newer sdk version #33 Error

Tags: android, flutter

I wrote a code like this:

`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sms_inbox/flutter_sms_inbox.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Main());
    SmsQuery query = SmsQuery();
}
class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  const Main({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Main> createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  final SmsQuery _query = SmsQuery();
  List<SmsMessage> _messages = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _messages.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
              var message = _messages[i];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('${message.sender} [${message.date}]'),
                subtitle: Text('${message.body}'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            var permission = await Permission.sms.status;
            if (permission.isGranted) {
              final messages = await _query.querySms(
                kinds: [SmsQueryKind.inbox, SmsQueryKind.sent],
                // address: '+254712345789',
                count: 10,
              );
              debugPrint('sms inbox messages: ${messages.length}');
              setState(() => _messages = messages);
            } else {
              await Permission.sms.request();
            }
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error in the console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Dosyalar\Yazilim\Flutter\Teen Message\teenmessage\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl61875986.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #7): Requires newer sdk version #33 (current version is #29)]
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.
Exited (sigterm)
```

How can I solve the problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: you are using package that require newer sdk. you have to change id on gradle file

Answer (score 0):

You can see the problem clearly in the error message.

> adb: failed to install C:\Dosyalar\Yazilim\Flutter\Teen Message\teenmessage\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: **Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK**: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl61875986.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #7): Requires newer sdk version #33 (current version is #29)]

As you can see above, the error is due to an older SDK version. So, install the required SDK version to get rid of this error.

In order to `install New SDK version`strong text, you can follow the following steps:

1. Open Android Stdio
2. Setting > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK
3. Now click on `SDK Platforms`
4. Check the required `SDK version = 33`
5. And Click on `Apply`

[image: Flutter - Requires newer sdk version #33 Error]

Comment: Should only API Level 33 be selected?

Comment: Currently Android 11 (R) and Android API 33 are selected and I still get the same error.

Comment: Try to update the SDK versions of the project in the build configurations file from android>app>build.gradle . You can see this setting in the section of the default configuration. You can get help from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project

I hope it will help you to solve your problem.