# how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to open existing android project in android studio and it gradle cannot build the app without the error

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:.
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

For our Flutter Project: Navigate to app-level build.gradle file. Change compileSdkVersion from 30 to 31 and Change targetSdkVersion from 30 to 31

Comment: Shows same error.

Comment: You will find the answer to your question in this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/flutter-how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project