# how can i solve problems in vscode?

Tags: flutter, gradle, debug-console

while running my flutter project in VScode, I get this error from the debug console, can you help?

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0] C:\Users\mert.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0077406c1c464d0bcfe637e4730a3849\transformed\jetified-firebase-analytics-21.3.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
> or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
> or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.firebase_analytics" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

I tried many things but it didn't work

Comment: As said, your android sdk version mismatch between two manifests.
You need to set the correct version to use.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/flutter-how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project

Comment: You need to upgrade the SDk version in build.gradle file in android filder

Comment: Thank you for all suggestions . I fixed the problem