# Flutter app doesn´t compile in android after adding dependency to pubspec.yml

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, flutter

I have added the simple_permissions dependency to a flutter app i'm developing, but after adding it the app wont build with the next error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on LG M700 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I already had this dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  path: ^1.6.2
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  open_file: ^1.2.2+2
```

This compiles fine, but after adding `simple_permissions: ^0.1.9` the app wont compile. I have already tried some solutions that required changes in the `build.gradle` file but they havent worked either, like changing the sdk version from 27 to 28 and adding this piece of code:

```
project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the build fails generating the dex list.

I'm developing the app using vscode and running the app in my smartphone.

I would be really grateful if you could help me with this.

Comment: Looks like you need to enable multidex https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a lot problem with the simple_permissions.
I ended up to use permission_handler

Comment: I changed it but the problem with simple_permissions wasn't solved

Answer (score 1):

Try changing buildToolsVersion to "23.0.3" (old, but stable), and then go to `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` and select `Restart`.

If that doesn't work, delete your "build" folders (if they exist), and then retry.

If both fails, you can just [enable multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680454/7280432). But this is a bad approach and should not be done under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I upgraded my flutter sdk then this problem had been solved ...

It happens because some packages of Flutter make conflict with Androidx LifeCycle. So you need to upgrade the Flutter then run your app.... I think then there should not be no Errors like this...

For Flutter type "flutter upgrade" in your terminal...

Answer (score 0):

**1st Solution**
You need to update your flutter sdk to the latest version. On the recent flutter stable release (2.10) they have automatically enabled Multidex. So you will have no problem to run it.

To upgrade to latest stable release visit [documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels#how-to-change-channels)

**2nd Solution**

If you build your project with older versions (below 2.10), check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886597/multidex-issue-with-flutter/60158352)