# flutter build error - merging dex archives

Tags: android, error-handling, build, flutter, dex

I upgraded flutter today (flutter update) and the packages (flutter packages update) and since my app does not build.

This is the output I get (after trying to change the sdk from 27 to 28 and clean)

I would appreciate your help.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on in debug mode...
```

Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of device_info will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See hfor more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\271.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\272.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\273.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\274.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\275.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\276.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\277.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\278.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\279.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\280.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\281.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\282.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\283.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\284.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\285.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\286.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\287.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\288.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\289.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\290.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\291.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\292.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\293.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\294.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\295.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\296.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\297.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\298.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\299.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\300.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\301.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\302.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\303.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\304.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\305.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\306.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\307.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\308.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\309.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\310.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\311.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\312.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\313.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\314.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\315.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\316.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\317.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\318.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\319.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\320.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\321.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\322.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\323.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\324.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\325.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\326.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\327.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\328.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\329.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\330.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\331.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\332.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\333.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\334.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\335.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\336.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\337.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\338.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\339.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\340.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\341.jar, C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\git\XX\app\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\342.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 10):

## [Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680454) by [Yuri Misyac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4149649/yuri-misyac)

---

1. **Enable multidex.**

Open `{your flutter project}/android/app/build.gradle` and add following lines.

```
defaultConfig {
  ...

  multiDexEnabled true // Add this line
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
  ...

  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // Add this line
}
```

2. **Migrate to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)**.

Open `{your flutter project}/android/gradle.properties` and add following lines.

```
...  
android.useAndroidX=true // Add this line
android.enableJetifier=true //Add this line
```

---

#### More info:

- [Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680454) *(Check this if it still doesn't work)*
- [Enable Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)
- [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)