# Getting "app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug" error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am getting this error while building the app. I have done all the changes related to MULTIDEX but still getting this error.

Comment: i have same issue, I think it's a bug with some packages.

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: I have encountered. image_picker package, so remove the package. and no error

Comment: If I removed image_pciker then whats the alternative ?

Comment: i use imager_picker_modern https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_modern

Comment: How to check that which library is conflicting ? And thanks for the help.

Comment: In my case, I checked one by one. I tried changing the application to multidexapplication in android but it didn't work. It does not work properly. Maybe this part won't be fixed when flutter upgrade later?

Comment: i found this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680454/4997344

Comment: Thanks for the link. One morething is there any file picker I can use. I tried few but they are not working.

Comment: Please suggest me any good file picker with sample code. Thanks in advance

Comment: File picker? Image picker?

Comment: Image picker issue resolve and thanks for it but I am also looking for FILE Picker :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707395/is-there-any-file-picker-i-can-use-i-tried-few-but-they-are-not-working

Comment: Any thing on this ?

Comment: i Reply that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707395/is-there-any-file-picker-i-can-use-i-tried-few-but-they-are-not-working

Comment: I am getting issue in https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_modern - As image is not setting after selecting the image from Gallery. Below is my code: 


// For Capturing the image
Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      imageData = image;
      displayImage = "Yes";
      
    });
  }

Answer (score 0):

Android MultiDex Error Solution

Link : stackoverflow.com/a/54680454/4997344