# Flutter app errors will trying to connect with Firebase and Auth

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, visual-studio-code

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
    Note: /Users/Robert/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore- 
    0.13.3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java 
    uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 87901 > 65536)
    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
    The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
    Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 87901 > 65536)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile.a(:33)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile$h.a(:5)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.a(:13)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.write(:35)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:44)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:23)
    ... 36 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
[!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
    To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
    To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

My Flutter app was working. 
I connected my stand alone app to Firebase 
I followed this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#add-flutterfire-plugins

Before I mess up my installation and App.
Hopefully some one is able to help me out.

I'm working on a Macbook with Android Studio, emulator, and VS Code running. 
Thanks for your time! 
Robert

Answer (score 3):

this is a multiDex issue. as you can see here in the stack trace `Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html`

Add the following in the defaultConfig section of your android/app/build.gradle

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

And under the dependencies add the following

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

This will enable multidex support.

#### References

1. [From Android (Also in Stack Trace)](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)
2. [Stack overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886597/multidex-issue-with-flutter)
3. [Medium explaining](https://medium.com/@olawale_alabi/android-flutter-64k-methods-dex-limit-how-to-use-proguard-in-development-728af11a4e22)

Answer (score 1):

First of all what you proposed is working!

But is it possible to change the settings in the file android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.flutter_course"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
```

and change the minSdkVersion 16 to 21?
And where can I find the latest version of minSdkVersion, so I can keep it up to date?

Thank you for your help!