# Flutter Program Works on Web but Not Running on Android Device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

This Flutter program works in on the Web, but doesn't on Android

How do I fix the code to run this on Android Device.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:html';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [TextEditingController()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ...List.generate(
            controllers.length,
            (index) => TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              controller: controllers[index],
              onSubmitted: (v) {
                controllers.add(TextEditingController());
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING - https://pastebin.com/KmcHFs1X

Comment: this link if for the second error, when you remove the imports https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680454/12156637

Comment: remove `import 'dart:html';`