# app bundle not building after update of flutter where as app debug builds but not app release

Tags: flutter, build, flutter-dependencies

My Error Code

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 35s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            158.6s
[!] App requires Multidex support
Multidex support is required for your android app to build since the number of methods has exceeded 64k. You may
pass the --no-multidex flag to skip Flutter's multidex support to use a manual solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code in app/build.gradle file to enable multidex support.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    ....
}
```

See [Enable multidex for apps with over 64K methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) for details.

Comment: already Did :defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.tpfcnepal.totalphysical"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    } Still not working

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886597/multidex-issue-with-flutter